# how to display trace data in zipkin using playframework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.4, zipkin

i am running zipkin via docker with this command docker `run -d -p 9411:9411 openzipkin/zipkin` and accessing its server at http://localhost:9411/zipkin/ 
I am using playframework-2.4 i am not getting the service name in zipkin ui also trace data is now showing up it shows `0 of 0 services`

here is my code 
application.conf

```
play.http.filters=arteciate.filters.Filters

trace {
  service-name = "zipkin-api-sample"

  zipkin {
    base-url = "http://localhost:9411"
    sample-rate = 0.1
  }
}

zipkin-trace-context {
  fork-join-executor {
    parallelism-factor = 20.0
    parallelism-max = 200
  }
}

play.modules.enabled  += "jp.co.bizreach.trace.play24.module.ZipkinModule"
```

build.sbt

```
"jp.co.bizreach" %% "play-zipkin-tracing-play24" % "1.2.0" 

class DirectUserController @Inject() (userRepository: UserRepositoryTrait, val tracer: ZipkinTraceService)
   extends Controller with ZipkinTraceImplicits {
   // Trace blocking action
  def test1 = Action { implicit request =>
    tracer.trace("sync"){ implicit traceData =>
      log.info("Hello World!")
      Ok(Json.obj("result" -> "ok"))
    }
  }
}
```

i am accessing `http://localhost:9000/direct-user/test1` it first then http://localhost:9411 but trace data is not showing up 
is there any thing missing ?please help